# Remove lines with crazy symbols

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessor

I have a list with sentences and some of them have been encoded incorrectly I believe. Some sentences contain strings like 'hÃ©' now. I want to remove all of the sentences, containing words with crazy symbols like that. I have tried the code below, which has worked partly. Lots of the sentences I wanted to remove have been removed, but not all of them. Any ideas?

```
clean_sentences = []
lines_to_erase = []
characters = "Ã©Â�Ä¢¬"
for line in all_data:
    for char in line:
      if char in characters:
        lines_to_erase.append(line)
for line in all_data:
    if line not in lines_to_erase:
        clean_sentences.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

`len(x) == len(x.encode())`

this returns True if the character is a generic ascii value

using this you could iterate through all of the characters and return the text but without the non ascii characters

```
[x for x in arr if len(x) == len(x.encode())]
```

if you want to remove all the sentences with any non ascii characters iterate through all the lines and then if it encounters a non ascii character it wont add it to the final list

```
end = []
for x in sentences:
    badchar = false
    for char in x:
        if len(char) == len(char.encode()):
            badchar = True
            break
    if not(badchar): end.append(sentence)
```

Comment: btw `"\b"` and `"\r"` and `"\x00"` are all ascii chars but aren't considered valid

Comment: oh yea this is true so adding an `and in "\b\r\x00"` to the if statement should work if I'm not mistaken

Comment: What about `"\x01"`, `"\x02"`, ...? Use `<str>.isprintable`

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with english text, you could use translate() to detect the presence of non-printable ascii characters:

```
import string

invalidChars = str.maketrans('','',string.printable) # remove valid characters

all_data = ["Good line.",
            "Bad Ã©Â�Ä¢¬ line",
            "Other good line"]

clean_sentences = [line for line in all_data if not line.translate(invalidChars)]

print(*clean_sentences,sep="\n")

Good line.
Other good line
```

You can also do this the other way around, by specifying the characters that are invalid.

```
validChars = str.maketrans('','','Ã©Â�Ä¢¬')

all_data = ["Good line.",
            "Bad Ã©Â line with �Ä¢¬ characters",
            "Other good line"]

clean_sentences = [line for line in all_data if line == line.translate(validChars)]

print(*clean_sentences,sep="\n")

Good line.
Other good line
```

However, if the text has been badly encoded/decoded, you should find that the "crazy symbols" always start with the same 2 character patterns (of which there should be few variations).  In that case it would probably be better to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to find if a line has "Ã©Â�Ä¢¬" in it, not one of them. What you can do instead is change the variable 'characters' into a list containing those characters. Something like:

```
clean_sentences = []
lines_to_erase = []
characters = ["Ã", "©", "Â", "�", "Ä", "¢", "¬"]
for line in all_data:
    for char in line:
      if char in characters:
        lines_to_erase.append(line)
for line in all_data:
    if line not in lines_to_erase:
        clean_sentences.append(line.strip())
```

So in this case, your checking if a line contains any of the characters in the "characters" Variable.